# How can I maximize the probability that my ETH nodes stay synchronized with mainnet for as long as possible?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, synchronization, mining-pools, ethminer

I run three full ETH nodes, one on my local, home network, and two in the cloud. All three make use of geth.

My "local" node, is *always* in sync with mainnet, i.e. always showing the same last block number (or within 1 or 2 blocks of the same number) as the LAST BLOCK number shown on Etherscan.io.

My "cloud" nodes, on the otherhand, spend the majority (yes, the majority!) of their time lagging by hundreds (or even thousands) of blocks behind mainnet. This situation has persisted for several months. To be clear, that is to say that there are times when the nodes are fully synced, but this situation will last for no more than a few hours, and then the nodes will spend 24 - 48 - 72 hrs lagging, and lagging badly...

In case it is relevant, one of the "cloud" nodes is mining with multiple remote miners (approx 20, using ethminer, with total hashing power approx 3.2 GH/s). The other "cloud" node is a fail-over node in case the first has problems, but it is generally not supporting remote miners at any given point in time. Both of these "cloud" nodes are suffering from the same syncing problem.

So, does anyone have any suggestions or tips for keeping ETH nodes synced? Why does my "local" node manage this effortlessly, while my "cloud" nodes are making a "hash" (and an "ethash") of it?

Comment: I'd imagine it's simply a matter of different resources. Connectivity / hardware / operating system / something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides what Nikita said, there is the chance that your problem is related to which ports are open. Be sure to open port 30303 (or your discovery port) so other nodes can find you (if you want to) and have as many peers as posible.

Answer (score 4):

> My "cloud" nodes, on the otherhand, spend the majority (yes, the majority!) of their time lagging by hundreds (or even thousands) of blocks behind mainnet.

Syncing heavily relies on the IOPS performance of your drive. Having a node in a cloud, you most probably share the performance of a drive with others. To resolve this issue you need to get a dedicated server with a proper SSD.